# how to create type using specified schema in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, schema

I want to create a type or sequence with my owner schema, but when I create, it always in public schema. what should I do?
Can you help me ?

Comment: Please show us your SQL statements. Most likely you don't use a schema qualification.

Comment: Prefix your object with the schema name:  create sequence hambone.sales_order_id, where hambone is the schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TYPE my_schema.my_type as ENUM ('yes', 'no', 'maybe');
```

So basically you put the schema name before the type name and separate them with a dot.